# How to get all Checked Out documents in a site collection using Search?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search, sharepoint-on-prem

I need to get all documents that are currently checked out in a site collection or web application using search.
Also I need to get the time at which they were checked out.

Is it possible to this with search only.

**Note: This whole process must be done through SharePoint search only.**

Comment: I think you will not be able to do it with search since search only indexes checked-in / major versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mind you, you can do this but there are limitations...

- Files that have never been checked in cannot be indexed, therefore they will never be found by the search.
- If you were to access a file from the search that is checked out, you would be in fact opening the last checked in version.

So the column you are interested in is **CheckoutUser**. If a file is checkedout, this column will have a value. If the file is not checked out, this column will be blank. This column's crawled property points to the managed property **mvCheckoutUser**.

So all you had to do is search for mvCheckoutUser when it is not empty. Here you may have to be a little hacky and do something like:

mvCheckoutUser:a OR mvCheckOutUser:b OR mvCheckOutUser:c ...

Comment: I think this could work, but you'll need the wildcards: mvCheckoutUser:"a*" OR mvCheckOutUser:"b*" ...

Comment: Agreed.  That's the weak part about it.

Comment: I could not find any Managed property with this name. Does this have the same name in SharePoint Online as well ?

Comment: That is a really good question. Myself I was using SharePoint 2016. Might I suggest for you looking at the crawled properties section and search CheckoutUser. Thats the column we care about, and there you should be able to see what crawl properties pull from it, and from there what managed properties access it.

Comment: @KyleRogers-Brodeur I was able to find Managed Property named "CheckoutUserOWSUser" after crawling my site. I will try to work with that. Thanks. Do we have something for finding duration of checkout?

Comment: Hi @Shashank. I am afraid there does not appear to be a property that controls the date / time of the checkout. If you found my response helpful, may I ask you to mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/spo-export-checked-out-files-in-tenant-using-search/README.html?tabs=pnpps as an example on how to extract to a csv file